# Is there an OS X desktop client for BlockChain.info?

Tags: blockchain.info

I know it may be  possible to achieve on Bitcoin-Qt app but don't want to download the whole blockchain into my laptop. I just want a desktop GUI for my BlockChain.info wallets. Is this possible? If so, what client does that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a chrome extension that can operate offline.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/my-wallet/djjkppdfofjnpcbnkkangbhanjdnoocd?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon